# Salvar posições de um arquivo texto em variáveis usando PHP

Tags: php

Preciso ler um arquivo de texto para posteriormente salva los no banco de dados, onde os valores são nomeados em registos do tipo :

**01**: $cnpj = Posição 03 a 16 , $numero = Posição 17 a 16 
 **02**: $CodigoBarras = Posição 3 a 15 , $quantidadef = Posição 29 a 35 
 **03**: $quantidade = Posição 03 a 16

> Sendo que o registo do tipo **02** pode ter mais de uma linha, pois de trata de itens de um pedido.

A imagem em anexo demonstra o layout do arquivo a ser lido:

[image: ARQUIVO DE TEXTO MENCIONADO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railam,
Utilize a função **file_get_contents** em conjunto com um **explode**

```
$linhas = explode("\n", file_get_contents(caminho/do/arquivo));
```

Após isso use a função **substr**

```
$cnpj = substr($linhas[0],3,16);
```

Precisa confirmar o que está retornando nas variaveis.

Mas isso seria feito em todos os casos listados só precisa acertar as posições de "Corte"

Se o padrão que seguir for o do arquivo informado segue exemplos para obter os outros registros.

```
$total = count($linhas);


$quantidade = substr($linhas[($total - 1)],3,16);

for ($i=1; $i < $total-2; $i++) { 
    $CodigoBarras[] = substr($linhas[$i],3,15);
    $quantidadef[] = substr($linhas[$i],29,35);
}

var_dump($CodigoBarras,$quantidadef);
```

Comment: Esqueci de informar, mas as linhas que você busca, exemplo a 1, sempre estará um indexe a baixo, então se for a linha 13 será o indexe 12 na array gerada ($linhas)

Comment: Certo ! testei aqui e esta me atendendo parcialmente , meu problema agora é com o registo **02**  caso o mesmo apareça mais de uma vez no arquivo . pois se trata de itens . . .

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo de como seria com mais de um código de barras?

Comment: Segue arquivo onde o registo do tipo 02 repete: https://pastebin.com/raw/fTmKBp4r

Comment: Entendi, então é bem simples. Pegue o total de registros no array $linhas, remova 2 (o primeiro e ultimo, sempre padrão). E inicie um loop que percorra a array $linhas do index 1 até o tamanho total do $linhas - 2. Estou indo para casa no momento. De lá posso estar enviando um exemplo se preferir.

Comment: Já para o ultimo registro é só obter o total e descontar um que você conseguirá normal.

Comment: Ficarei grato se me ajudar com isto , estou tentando por aqui também , desde já  agradeço sua ajuda. Grato.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, voltei para o PC só agora

Comment: Railam, deu certo a resposta?

Comment: Olá , certo , fiz algumas  modificações para me atender, mas ocorreu tudo certo ! Obrigado meu amigo.

Comment: Que bom, por favor, informe como respondida a pergunta.